# Is there an equivalent to nsIBrowserSearchService for WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I tried to create a Firefox 57+ compatible add-on (i.e. a WebExtensions based add-on) containing the following code:

```js
// Import the Services module.
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var bss = Services.search; // browser search service
bss.init();
var searchEngines = bss.getVisibleEngines({});
```

only to learn that **[you can't import Services using the WebExtensions API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332561/firefox-webextension-importing-services)**.

So, I'm wondering if there's an equivalent way, using the WebExtensions API, to be able to access a browser's search bar search engines (that will be compatible with Firefox 57+ and not break with Firefox 56-).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Add context menu in bookmark menu of Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44351539)

Answer (score 2):

This is still being decided see:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268401

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment than an answer. You could flesh it out to the point that it made a reasonable answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Andrew. I found it helpful, but I'll for a solution to be available before I vote for an Answer that solves my problem. Hope fully, we won't have to wait too long before a solution is proposed by the Firefox developers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API yet, but a "searchengines" API will probably added in the future. It is yet unclear if it will support adding search engines, but listing existing search engines will be definitely a thing.

Bug 1268401 - Add APIs to manage search engines for the web search bar/location bar
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268401

Bug 1352598 - Add an API to list installed search engines
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1352598

This was a suggestion to implement a searchengines API (linked in bug report 1352598):
https://gist.github.com/nt1m/cad0b5afb35785d051785a51a4f6cf98

Comment: Hello Smile4ever, I find your contributions very helpful. Thank you. What's your real name? So far, I haven't been able to create a firefox extension that integrates with the search engines from the search bar, but I would be grateful if you would provide me with your feedback for the extension which can be found here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/contextual-search/?src=ss

Comment: Hi Olivier de Broqueville. You can fill out the contact form on my website to get in touch: http://hugsmile.eu